# Fluent Nhibernate working with entities after session disposed

Tags: session, memory-leaks, fluent-nhibernate, dispose

I've got a question about working with entities which were received from db.
Currently I've a lot of operations, where I need to get entities from db, and pass them to another service. Simplified version of such code are is like this:

```
List<Entity> list;
using(var session = SessionFactory.OpenSession())
{
    list = Session.QueryOver<Entity>.Future().ToList();
}
```

So now I don't know, if list of objects isn't disposed for a long time, will it cause memory lear accordint to stored sessions. Does nhibernate sessions exist while exist objects which were received during the session?

**Update**:

Found some session setting Session.ActiveEntityMode - POCO, does it solves my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the session is disposed as soon as the using ends. All entities loaded are still valid except not initialized lazyloaded collections/references/properties.

Also the Future in `Session.QueryOver<Entity>.Future().ToList();` is a noop when there are no other operations befor which have Future/futurevalue on them.

Comment: Thanks, already made some high load tests to prove POCO mode on session.